# Does "Garbage Enzyme cleaner" contain enzymes?

Tags: biology, cleaning, yeast

There are [many recipes which call for using fruit peel anaerobic fermentation process](http://happyhomemaker88.com/2009/05/02/recipe-for-homemade-citrus-enzyme-a-natural-cheap-effective-all-purpose-cleaner/) to make a concentrated enzyme cleaner solution. So the question arises that does this recipe really have those [cleaning  enzymes](http://www.cleanlink.com/casestudieswhitepapers/details/Green-Cleaning-Understanding-Bioenzymatic-Cleaners--24615) apart from the usual alcohol and how are these enzymes generated?

[This article says](http://littlehouseinthesuburbs.com/2013/07/7-things-you-should-know-before-making-citrus-enzyme-cleaner.html) that it may not have enzymes but some other cleaning agents like vinegar and alcohol.

[A discussion from two independent researchers on this topic give seemingly contrasting positions](http://www.ecowalkthetalk.com/blog/2011/03/04/responses-how-effective-are-garbage-enzymes/)

Comment: Is that page essentially saying that there are enzymes in it (from the yeast) but because commercial cleaners do not use yeast enzymes there are no enzyme in it?

Comment: The first link names it @enzyme@ cleaner

Answer (score 1):

**What chemicals can be produced from orange peels?**

A [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=viAtAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA138&dq=%22Biorefinery%20of%20waste%20orange%20peel%22&pg=PA138#v=onepage&q=%22Biorefinery%20of%20waste%20orange%20peel%22&f=false) summary of a [recent review article](http://informahealthcare.com/doi/abs/10.3109/07388550903425201) informs me that the article says that the chemicals that can plausibly be made from orange peels include D-limonene, pectin, ethanol, methane, and pectinase. The reason I assume this list is complete is because it comes from a review article summarizing everything that orange juice manufacturers are trying to do to recycle orange peels. If you could make eco-friendly Windex from them, the Tropicana company would be jumping on it.

**Can these chemicals help in cleaning?**

Yes, ethanol is great for cleaning stuff and D-limonene smells like orange. But I believe you figured this out yourself.

I am satisfied from the review article above that the only enzyme easily extractable from orange peels is pectinase, which helps break down fruit fibers into sugars. You can use it to make liquor.

**Conclusion**

Orange peels and sugar make a natural ethanol solution that smells nice.

Comment: thanks , but do these enzyme survive the process

Comment: Please don't hurt me if this is wrong (I failed high school chemistry), but enzymes generally assist in chemical changes, and I am reading online that pectinase helps make this ethanol. So I am assuming the pectinase is still there as long as the fermentation is not complete. But it's not a cleaning agent, unless if you are making juice or liquor.